# Plus / Minus button change text instead of numbers

Tags: html

as I mention in the title, I want to achieve situation like this...

instead of numbers it should say "-- (sehr schlecht), -(schlecht), 0 (ok), + (gut), ++ (sehr gut)

There are too many examples where we can change numbers, but what's about text.

Instead of numbers I need to display text. When open the page, default value will be for example "Ok" value, when you click on " + " , text in input field should be changed to gut, another click on " + " , input should be changed to "sehr gut" . The same situation for " - "

Any suggestions ? Thanks is advance

Comment: What do you need, what did you try, what did you get, how is it different from what you need? Those are questions you should answer in your question, and you currently only partially answered the first one.

Comment: Instead of numbers I need to display text. When open the page, default value will be for example "Ok" value, when you click on " + " , text in input field should be changed to gut, another click on " + " , input should be changed to "sehr gut" . The same situation for " - "

Comment: How does this comment differ from your question? I understood that, but what about the other 3 questions I asked you? Please, edit your question *and provide code*.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont have the code. I dont have idea what to try about this solution.

Comment: You said "*instead of numbers*" which seems to indicate you have a solution that works with numbers. Or do you think SO is a free code writing service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that perfectly fits my needs

[Demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Select-Based-Input-Spinner-Plugin-For-jQuery-Select-Step/)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in input form to spin words like HTML5 input type number?

You must make a DIV that is contenteditable and makes CSS look like a form via CSS. After adding + and - buttons with a position absolute to that looks like input type number and after that just use JavaScript, put into an array list of words and rotate using + and - buttons.

**[QUICK EXAMPLE][1]**

```css
.input-spin{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  position:relative;
  min-height:22px;
}

.input-btn{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  padding:2px 3px;
  width:15px;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:console;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  line-height:10px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.input-btn:hover{
  background:#ccc;
}
.input-btn.minus{
  top:13px;
}
.input{
  padding:5px 10px;
  margin-right:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-spin">
  <div class="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="input-btn plus">+</div>
  <div class="input-btn minus">-</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ivijan, that's what I want, can you help me about JS code ?